# How to set certificate friendly name

Tags: c#, x509certificate

My aim is change a certificate friendly name because I have to pass unique alias to external aplication... I wrote this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
   X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
   X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection);

   foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in scollection)
        {
            try
            {
                String originName = friendlyNameOrigin(x509);  //get orginal friendlyname
                String nameNormalized = GetHashString(normalize(friendlyNameMy(x509))); //create 'uniqualy' name as md5 code
                MessageBox.Show(x509.FriendlyName);  //showed orginal name
                x509.FriendlyName = nameNormalized;
                MessageBox.Show(x509.FriendlyName);  //showed new name
                x509.Reset();
                //next line  - I started external aplication but it still see orginal name
                //var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", "-jar dist3/Signer.jar \"" + nameNormalized + "\" " + path);
                //DO SOMETHING
                //x509.FriendlyName = originName;
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
            }
        }
        store.Close();
}
```

This code change friendly name but windows OS still see old name (when programs run and after this). This mean that setting friendly name don't change friendlyname of certificate.

Can you say me how I can change friendlyname of certificate?

Thank you for a answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the store. Example code below:

Let's assume that Certificate is a X509Certificate2 object.

```
Certificate.FriendlyName = "New Friendly Name";
var store = new X509Store("My");
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(Certificate);
```